# Как стримить экран и иметь возможность говорить со зрителями?

Tags: браузер, аудио, streaming

Есть машина на windows. Необходимо в реальном времени транслировать картинку и звук клиентам и иметь возможность с ними общаться голосом. Видео+аудио должно записываться (знаю как это реализовать отдельно), но главное чтоб зрителям не нужно было ничего кроме браузера и была возможность говорить со стримером. Это возможно вообще?

Answer (score 1):

В принципе возможно. Копайте в сторону документаии Web API. А конкретно интерфейс MediaStream Recording должен подойти для ваших целей [подробней здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API)

Comment: Поискал примеры реализации этой штуки, ни один из них ни в одном из браузеров не работает. Не подскажете что-то готовое/работающее?